# Fast or rolling contact importer

Tags: web, import-contacts

Im trying to add a feature to my website that involves the typical "invite your friends" with help from a contact importer (cloudsponge). Its a pretty popular and gets the job done but I need something faster..

The problem with cloudsponge is that they request all contacts in one call, this could mean a long wait time for someone with alot of contacts.

I looked at their rest calls and there doesnt seem to be a way to load contacts in pieces. Do any of these contact importing services allow you to pull in a few contacts at a time (lets say 50) so that we can show our user the first 50 contacts and load the rest / updating the view.  So they dont have to wait forever for all the contacts to be pulled?

Ive looked at other apis like context io but cant seem to find a solution to this one.

Answer (score 1):

I built the CloudSponge API.

Early on, we decided to support imports across a variety of providers while exposing a simple and consistent interface. Pagination and rolling or real-time access to contacts were things that were excluded in order to do that.  To provide end-user feedback on the progress of the import, we added the /events endpoint.

So far import speed hasn't been a major issue for a couple reasons:

1. In general, end users with an address book of 10000+ contacts are rare (although this may not be the case for certain niches).
2. End users who do have this many contacts in their address book usually understand that it will take a while to import.

Having said that, the speed is something that we can definitely improve upon. Here's a few ideas:

1. We can allow for returning only a subset of all contacts by default. For example, we currently return all contacts for Gmail, which is usually a much larger number of contacts than are actually stored in 'my contacts'.
2. We can implement parallel paginated imports on the server side. This will make our server process work harder and faster to download the user's contacts from, say, Gmail. This adds complexity on our side but keeps the API untouched.
3. We can implement your suggestion: add a rolling or real-time access to contacts in our API, either in an extended endpoint or a new version of our interface.

I'm happy to work with you on exploring these to improve our service. Send us an email: support@cloudsponge.com

Graeme